# Naming of symbols in Fortran shared library, intel vs gcc?

Tags: fortran, shared-libraries, gfortran

Is there a way to control the naming of symbols in shared libraries?  Specifically, I've been using GCC for a project where we access shared library through C-Types in Python.  This works great, however recently I've been working with a system where the Intel compiler is suggested.  I can build the shared object just fine but I find the symbols have a slightly different naming convention as compared to intel.  Specifically when I compile with gcc the symbol names look like:

```
__test_function_MOD_read_a_file
```

the Intel compiled shared object has the symbol names like:

```
test_function_mp_read_a_file__
```

Is there a way to force consistency of the naming or at least change the name of the symbols after the fact?

For example consider the following bit of code test_function.f90

```
MODULE test_function
   CONTAINS
   SUBROUTINE read_a_file
      PRINT *,'I did a thing!'
   END SUBROUTINE
END
```

The compile line should look something like

```
gfortran -fPIC -c test_function.f90
gfortran -shared -o libtest_function.so test_function.o
```

Comment: Your question really has *nothing* to do with shared libraries, and *everything* to do with Fortran. "How can I make `gfortran` and Intel `ifort` have consistent names for external functions?" is how I would phrase this.

Comment: mod files and their symbol mangling are totally incompatible among different compilers, even between major releases of the same compiler.

Comment: Of course, if you declare variables like real(C_FLOAT)  bind(C,name=....) x you can control exactly the symbol name as seen by a compatible C compiler.

Comment: The code of subroutines and functions that require modules can easily be completely incompatible between compilers. For example, the array descriptors of GCC and Intel are different. Such code will then crash when used between these two.

Comment: If you wish to use array descriptors in this context, it should be possible with the new F2008 feature if your compiler implements it, as long as the Fortran compilers are compatible with the same C compiler.

Comment: @tim18 But only in `bind(C)` procedures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both compilers are mangling the names of the subprograms contained in the module.  The Fortran standard does not mandate any naming convention.  You can prevent the name mangling by using the ISO C Binding feature of Fortran to give the subprogram a specific name.  For example,

```
module bar
   contains
   function fun(x) bind(c, name='foo')
       real fun, x
       fun = x
   end function fun
   function goo(x)
       real goo, x
       goo = x
   end function goo
end module bar
```

When compiled with gfortran the resulting object file contains

```
gfortran -c a.f90
nm a.o
00000000 T __bar_MOD_goo
00000013 T foo
```

Thus, you can reference function`fun` as `foo` in the library.  You'll probably also want to use the types defined by the `iso_c_binding` module.

Comment: This is the only portable option.